Firebase Auth Next.JS with middleware
Hello dev friends over there.
I faced an issue with Firebase authentication in Next(TypeScript).
I want to control with middleware about something like permission access.
But, When I use the auth.currentUser it will be null always so, I used useContext with AuthContext.Provider and useAuth hook things. but, in middleware I can't use that..
So how can I use the Firebase-well with middleware?
Here is my codebase & What I want.
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { auth } from './utils/firebase/config';

const protectedRoutes = ["/article/add"];

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const currentUser = auth.currentUser;
  console.log(`currentUser is : ${currentUser}`);
  
  const user = null;
  if (user == null && protectedRoutes.includes(request.nextUrl.pathname)) {
    const absoluteURL = new URL("/login", request.nextUrl.origin);
    return NextResponse.redirect(absoluteURL.toString());
  }
}

export const config = {
    matcher: [
      /*
       * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
       * - _next/static (static files)
       * - _next/image (image optimization files)
       * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
       * Feel free to modify this pattern to include more paths.
       */
      '/((?!_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|.*\\.(?:svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp)$).*)',
    ],
  }

Please let me know your opinion. 

Hi.
To use Firebase Auth with middleware there is this super nice library next-firebase-auth-edge which helps you achieving this.
There are also two sample projects which show how to set it up.

Thank you for your opinion. Isn't there another solution without dependency(library)?

Use the token and use the auth rest apis

I actually faced the same problem, and in the end, I stored the getIdToken() result from the login to the cookies.
With the access token (JWT form) in cookies, you can access it in Server Action, API handler, and Middleware. For you to verify it, a simple JWT decoder package can decode the JWT and verify the iat / exp accordingly.

When do you store the idToken as a cookie? I couldn't fine a listener to idTokenChange() for web and I read that the idToken is refreshed with a high frequency once every hour and occasionally in some events.
